# How to find and extract date in string with PHP?

Tags: php, string, date

How can i find date inside a string in PHP and extract it?'

example:  I have a date in string

```
$status = "OK, 26.10.2022 13:24:00, Delivered Zak";
```

but also next time i can only get string which looks like this:

```
$status = "28.10.2022 11:20:00, Delivered";
```

So explode it to the pieces by "," is not a option here, because everytime is in different position. How can i get this date everytime?
Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the date in the string :

```php
// examples
$statuses = [
    "OK, 26.10.2022 13:24:00, Delivered Zak",
    "28.10.2022 11:20:00, Delivered",
    ];

foreach ($statuses as $status) {

    // Grab 'xx.xx.xxxx xx:xx.xx' 
    preg_match('~\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~', $status, $matches);


    // Convert to date 
    // TODO : test if $matches is not empty
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", reset($matches));

    // echo formatted for the test
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2022-10-26 13:24:00
2022-10-28 11:20:00
```

Comment: Live example : https://3v4l.org/AKXTC

Comment: I was about to post that. If the required format is DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss like in your original example, then here's a regex: ```([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\.([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\.\d\d\d\d\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)```

Comment: I'm not good at building regex thanks guys! I didn't even think to use it. Now i will thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove spurious characters before and after the date expression. A..Z removes all uppercase letters. Simply using date_create will also recognize some other date formats.

```
$statuses = [
    "OK, 26.10.2022 13:24:00, Delivered Zak",
    "28.10.2022 11:20:00, Delivered",
    "christmas eve 24 Dec 2020 19:00",
    "ABC 2022-09-12 13:45, and so on",
];
foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    $date = date_create(trim($status,"A..Za..z, "));
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2022-10-26 13:24:00
2022-10-28 11:20:00
2020-12-24 19:00:00
2022-09-12 13:45:00
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/uqAmm

If trim is not sufficient for special cases or if only certain date formats are to be accepted, a preg_replace can be used instead of trim.

```
preg_replace('/^[^\d]*(.+?)[a-z ,]*$/iu','$1',$status);
```